# How to replace this recessed light bulb

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I've been struggling with this light bulb for hours.
I tried to un-screw it to the left or right but it didn't rotate at all.
Please help me.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some types of compact fluorescent (PLL, PLT) have a push-in fitting. Try pulling straight out.

[image]
<sup>[Photo by ikiwaner, Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kompaktleuchtstofflampe.jpeg)</sup>

---

P.S. While you are working on that, you really ought to fix that loose earth/ground connection with a bolt, nut, washer and maybe a crimp-on ring-connector. Or something similar. —

P.P.S. broken compact fluorescents [may need special cleanup](https://www.epa.gov/cfl/cleaning-broken-cfl)

Comment: It looks like there may be a push in release tab at 1:30 o'clock on the base. Try pushing that tab in and pulling the base out. Use a garden glove to protect your hand